# Stream video on VLC Player over sftp with ssh key authorization

Tags: ssh, vlc-media-player, ssh-keys

So I know that I can stream media to VLC using sftp, however my server uses ssh-key authorization and not username/password. Is there any way to allow VLC to use my private ssh key to connect to my server so I can stream media thru sftp?

Comment: Same here, I have a key that I tested and works but VLC always prompts for credentials rather than using the key

Comment: Take a look at https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=144701

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to correctly format the MRL so that it works; for example:

```
sftp://victor@webserver/home/victor/hdd/Apricot.mp4
```

Specifying the user (`victor@`) is mandatory so that VLC uses your key.

In my specific case I'm using Dolphin (KDE) file browser, I changed the URL address from: (change `webserver` to the target IP address or hostname)

```
 sftp://webserver/home/victor/hdd/
```

To

```
 sftp://victor@webserver/home/victor/hdd/
```

That way when I open a remote media VLC doesn't ask for a password and is able to play the media.

Comment: That didnt work. When trying that it just asks for a username and password, which will not work on my system since I disabled password authentication. There must be a way to point VLC to the proper ssh key like you would in terminal (ie; ssh -i path_to_ssh_key username@server_ip_address/path_to_media)

Comment: Are you sure your SSH agent is properly configured? `eval \`ssh-agent\` && ssh-add` should do the trick, try again after making sure the SSH agent is running and configured with your key

Comment: Do I need to run that on the server I'm trying to connect to, or the client I'm connecting from? The machine I'm trying to connect from is Windows, and the ssh keys are stored somewhere other than the default folder ([external_drive]:\path\to\my\ssh\keys).

Comment: On the machine that is trying to connect to the other. I don't know the equivalent for Windows

Comment: It does not work. VLC on Android does not have a way to add path to private key. If login/password authentication is disabled I have to download the file first using sftp i.e. Total Command and then play media from local folder.

Comment: Does not work on Linux either. URL contained username@server from the beginning, but VLC still insists on password authentication rather than trying to use keys or ssh-agent.

Comment: It worked after executing ```eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add``` and starting vlc in the same terminal. I suggested to mention this in your answer because sometimes StackExchange comments are removed without any reason.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in this way:
**In the local machine** later you had set your public key in the server and set the local Dolphin in my case to does not aks for paraphrase, type in the local terminal:

```
ssh -vvv -i .ssh/id_rsa user@ip_address -p port_number

ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
```

Now go to VLC/Media/Open Network Stream.../Please enter a network URL:

```
sftp://user@ip_address:port_number//mnt/some_dir/
```

Click on Play.

Answer (score 1):

This question is super old, but I will answer anyway just in case someone else is having these issues, and the POSIX specific answers above cannot be used (as in the case of the Original Poster the client system is Windows).

The configuration you are looking for is NOT in VLC, but something you need to configure with your ssh-agent. I recommend using Putty for this on Windows. I have keypair authentication set up reliably from my lonely Windows 7 box to my Debian Subversion server, and Tortoise SVN doesn't need to know anything about the connection in the url other than the protocol and username@host and path of course. VLC should be no different.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue so I used `sshfs`.

You can find an example on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS:

```
mkdir ~/far_projects
sshfs -o idmap=user $USER@far:/projects ~/far_projects
```

This will allow you to play a video by opening it using your file manager.

Another advantage of sshfs is that vlc will show you the length of the video which was not the case for me when using sftp.